# Is there any way to get a widgets position relative to the entire screen in Tkinter?

Tags: python, geometry, screen, tkinter

I would like to know where exactly a widget is on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` methods of a widget.